# Как организовать доступ к сайту по https из защищенной сети с помощью nginx?

Tags: nginx

Имеется защищенная сеть, в которой прописали зону и все запросы к определенному сайту вида https://somesite.com резолвятся на IP сервера с nginx. Могу ли я теперь перенаправлять запросы от клиентов со своего nginx к этому целевому сайту?

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name somesite.com;  

 location = /403.html {
 }
 location / {
    proxy_pass https://somesite.com/;

  }
}
```

Я понимаю, что этот конфиг не работает, может кто-то подскажет как это лучше и правильно сделать?

Comment: в помощь: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/7031640 http://serverfault.com/q/583374/292034

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень помогло!

Comment: Eddy, опишите, пожалуйста, в ответе, что именно вы сделали. ответы на собственные вопросы здесь [приветствуются](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется собственный сертификат, то можно сделать так (у меня сработало):

```
server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name somesite.com;

 access_log /var/log/nginx/somesite-access.log;

    ssl_certificate      cert_mycert.ru;
    ssl_certificate_key  key_mycert_nopass.ru;

 location / {
    proxy_pass https://somesite.com/;
    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы отдаете свои внутренние IP внешнему сайту?.. Первые два `proxy_set_header` - попросту опасные. А третий `proxy_set_header ` - лишний, в вашей конфигурации заголовок Host и так уже правильный стоит.

Comment: То есть можно все set_header убрать?

Comment: Я бы сказал, нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил ответ.